# How can i select all previous elements's childs in css or with jquery?

Tags: css, parent

Well, i have a code like this:

```
<div class="code">
  <div>
  <input id="yellow" type="radio" name="yellow" value="1">
  <label for="yellow"> yellow</label>
  </div>
  <div>
  <input id="red" type="radio" name="red" value="2">
  <label for="red"> red</label>
  </div>
  <div>
  <input id="black" type="radio" name="black" value="3">
  <label for="black"> black</label>
  </div>
  <div>
  <input id="green" type="radio" name="green" value="4">
  <label for="green"> green</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let's imagine, that user have selected one of these radiobuttons, for example, "black". I need to add some css to "black" label and all the labels, that goes before "black" - "red" and "yellow" labels.

It have to be something like this:

```
.code > div > label:checked ~ label:before { some css }
```

But not exactly, cause labels are not just neighbors, they are nested in their divs. What i have to add/change to this css selecting rule?

Comment: You cannot select backwards or upwards in CSS. Not possible. Only forward and downward from any point in a selector you've already reached.

Comment: What styling do you want to do?

Comment: well, is it possible with jquery?

Comment: i want to color these labels, for example

Comment: So, i solved it with jquery :

function addColores() {
 var d = $("input:checked").closest("div").prevAll();
 d.each(function() {
  $( this ).find('label').addClass("colored");
});
   }

Comment: And i do not understand why this question is closed ;( It is not exactly the same as similar questions, and my solution with jquery, maybe, can help somebody

Comment: Alex, https://api.jquery.com/parent/ supports a selector so with jQuery you can get a child and then find a CSS selector above, this still should not be re-opened because no where have you tried some code and got a problem with the code your trying, and there are lots of questions about jQuery.parent(), and no backwards CSS selectors